# Adding new amount in database depending of switch case

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this in my controller

```
$shipping = array(
      'quantity' => 1,
      'image' => '/img/noimage.png',
      'description' => '',
      'title' => 'FIX ME', // this should never occur,
      'price' => 100000 // this should never occur
);
switch (Input::get('shipping_method')) {
     case Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_NORMAL:
          $shipping['title'] = 'Normal Delivery';
          $shipping['price'] = 0;
          break;

     case Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRESS:
          $shipping['title'] = sprintf('Express Delivery - $%.2f', Settings::getOption('express_shipping_cost'));
          $shipping['price'] = doubleval(Settings::getOption('express_shipping_cost'));
          break;
 }

 $cart['shipping'] = $shipping;
 $order = new Order();
 $order->data = json_encode($cart, true);
 $order->address = Input::get('shipping_address');
 $order->info = Input::get('additional_info');
 $order->price = Input::get('price');
 $order->save();
```

If user choose `Normal Delivery` price is +0 and I save `$order->price = Input::get('price');` this is only the product/s price.

How can I make here condition if user choose `Express Delivery` addition amount to be added to product price here
`$order->price = Input::get('price');` something like

```
if (Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRES)
{ $order->price = Input::get('price') + shipping_express_price; }
else  { $order->price = Input::get('price'); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (Input::get('shipping_method') == Settings::SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRESS)
{
    $order->price = Input::get('price') + shipping_express_price;
}
else
{
    $order->price = Input::get('price');
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer but when I run it got this error `'Undefined class constant 'SETTINGS_SHIPPING_EXPRES'`

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot one S at the and of the EXPRESS word. Now it should be working.

Comment: Now this `'Use of undefined constant shipping_express_price - assumed 'shipping_express_price''` What is  means?

Comment: made it like this `$order->price = Input::get('price') + $shipping['price'];` and looks like is working.